# Why would RTF files created with Pandoc be opened as plain text?

Tags: markdown, rtf, word-processing, text-formatting, pandoc

I'm experimenting with [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/), in particular the markdown to RTF function. When I run the converter, the resulting RTF is opened in both Word and OpenOffice as plain text (where the text looks like RTF, but isn't treated as RTF). Converting to HTML works fine.

Here is the command I used:

```
pandoc -f markdown -t rtf -o sample.rtf sample.txt
```

Here is the short sample markdown I used:

```
# markdown example

- uli1

_em_

__strong__
```

Snippet of the contents of the created file:

```
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li0 \fi0 \b \fs36 markdown example\par}
```

Running on Vista 32-bit, using Pandoc 1.6 (from http://code.google.com/p/pandoc/downloads/list).

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just need to use the '-s' (or '--standalone') option when invoking pandoc.  Otherwise pandoc produces a fragment, not a full standalone RTF file.

Comment: Thanks @John. That's the option I was looking for. I didn't comprehend from the docs how useful it would be.

Answer (score 2):

A rtf file should always begin with the [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) **`{\rtf`** *(and end in a matching **`}`**)*. Make sure the generated file starts with that. If it doesn't either there is a bug in pandoc or you are missing a setting somewhere.

I tried the [web version](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try) of Pandoc and it did not add **`{\rtf`** at the beginnig of the text.

Comment: Thanks Nifle - that was exactly the problem. After manually wrapping the file in the "magic number" it was loaded properly (I suspect a bug in the converter). Cheers!

Comment: @Ash - Glad to be of help